# Probability Theory ( Conditional probability)

Tags: probability-theory

A private facebook group can only be joined if someone from the group invites you. Originally, the group has two members : Adam and Eve. Occasionally a random person from the group invites a new member. Someone is part of Adam's clique if they are Adam themselves or if someone from Adam's clique invited them.

a) What is the probability of Adam's clique having $k$ members when the Facebook group has $4$ members? ($k=1,2,3$)

b) Let $X$ be the number of people in Eve's clique when Facebook has $n$ members. Give the distribution of $X$

I need help, for a) is it okay if i say for $k=1$ probability is $1/4$. For $k=2$ then $P=1/2$ and when $k=3$ then $P=1/4$

Then for part b) finding the distribution, I don't know how to solve that, How can i use mathematical induction to solve it

Please help

Comment: You don't explain where you got your answers for $a$, and it isn't obvious (to me, at least) that you are correct.  For example, for the $k=1$ case, the possible scenarios are "$E$ first invites $E_1$ and then $E$ invites $E_2$", and "$E$ first invites $E_1$ and then $E_1$ invites $E_2$".  Each of these has probability $\frac 12\times \frac 13=\frac 16$, so I get the answer $\frac 13$ for $k=1$.  Have I misunderstood (or miscomputed)?  How did you get $\frac 14$?

Comment: I said ;   all events = $4$, then apart from Adam, i need to choose 0-2 more people because Eve has to be in the group as well, which will be total of  4 people. So for  good events i said its 2 choose 0 which is 1

Comment: Can't follow, sorry.  Is my calculation flawed? If so, how?  I've written my reasoning out exactly...of course, I might well have misunderstood the rules.

Comment: There simply aren't very many scenarios to consider in the $4$ member case.  Letting $X\to Y$ mean "person $X$ invites person $Y$ to join" then we have $(A\to A_1,A\to A_2), (A\to A_1, A_1\to A_2), (A\to A_1, E\to E_1), (E\to E_1,E\to E_2), (E\to E_1, E_1\to E_2), (E\to E_1, A\to A_1)$.  Six scenarios, all equally likely.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I think your calculations are correct, I now understand.. Thanks for assistance..  Have any idea how to get distribution?

Comment: Well, I'd first check group size $5$.  The fact that the distribution is uniform for sizes $3,4$ is certainly suggestive.  Maybe it's always uniform! Worth a shot anyway. So check $5$ at least.  Once you have a sense of the answer, try to prove it recursively.